# Kickstart failing partition creation

Tags: rhel, partition, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I started with this in my kickstart file:

```
%pre

#***********************************************
#
# Get disk name to generate partition
#
#***********************************************
DIR="/sys/block"

# minimum size of hard drive needed specified in GIGABYTES
MINSIZE=50

ROOTDRIVE=""

# /sys/block/*/size is in 512 byte chunks

for DEV in xvda sda sdb sdc sdd; do
  if [ -d $DIR/$DEV ]; then
    REMOVABLE=`cat $DIR/$DEV/removable`
    if (( $REMOVABLE == 0 )); then
      echo $DEV
      SIZE=`cat $DIR/$DEV/size`
      GB=$(($SIZE/2**21))
      if [ $GB -gt $MINSIZE ]; then
        echo "$(($SIZE/2**21))"
        if [ -z $ROOTDRIVE ]; then
          ROOTDRIVE=$DEV
        fi
      fi
    fi
  fi
done

echo "ROOTDRIVE=$ROOTDRIVE"

cat > /tmp/ks-partition.txt <<EOF

# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=$ROOTDRIVE

# Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr

# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all

# Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --ondisk=$ROOTDRIVE --size=1000
part pv.00 --fstype="lvmpv" --ondisk=$ROOTDRIVE --size=1024 --grow
volgroup vg00 pv.00
logvol swap             --fstype="swap" --size=4096 --name=swap --vgname=vg00
logvol /var/log/audit   --fstype="ext4" --percent=10 --name=var_log_audit --vgname=vg00
logvol /var/log         --fstype="ext4" --percent=10 --name=var_log --vgname=vg00
logvol /var             --fstype="ext4" --percent=10 --name=var --vgname=vg00
logvol /opt             --fstype="ext4" --percent=30 --name=opt --vgname=vg00
logvol /                --fstype="ext4" --size=1000 --grow --name=root --vgname=vg00
EOF

%end
```

And wittled it all the way down to what you see below before it would work (many partial changes in between). Every time I kicked it I would see something like "is_valid_stage1_device: False" in the anaconda.log and it would ask me to manually configure partitioning to continue.  Any ideas?

Using 7.2 and the thing i'm kickstarting is a VM. To be clear the below works like a champ but I need/want to automate like the above.

```
# System bootloader configuration
bootloader --append=" crashkernel=auto" --location=mbr --boot-drive=xvda

# Clear the Master Boot Record
zerombr

# Partition clearing information
clearpart --all

# Disk partitioning information
part /boot --fstype=ext4 --ondisk=xvda --size=1000
part pv.00 --fstype="lvmpv" --ondisk=xvda --size=1024 --grow
volgroup vg00 pv.00
logvol swap             --fstype="swap" --size=4096 --name=swap --
vgname=vg00
logvol /var/log/audit   --fstype="ext4" --percent=10 --name=var_log_audit --vgname=vg00
logvol /var/log         --fstype="ext4" --percent=10 --name=var_log --vgname=vg00
logvol /var             --fstype="ext4" --percent=10 --name=var --vgname=vg00
logvol /opt             --fstype="ext4" --percent=30 --name=opt --vgname=vg00
logvol /                --fstype="ext4" --size=1000 --grow --name=root --vgname=vg00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!  It wasn't the %pre config at all... I missed the %include for the partition file... dumb.

Here's the line I added (outside of the %pre - above it in my case.)

```
%include /tmp/ks-partition.txt
```